# Android: Dialing a custom number once call picked up

Tags: android

I am working on an app that picks up a call, and in the dial pad during the active call, it enters a number previously saved or copied. First, I would like to know if this is even possible. Second, I have been thinking of some ideas, but I have no idea how wild they may be as I am relatively new to Android and have little idea about its limitations:

1. Store a number in the clipboard, and have some way to click paste in the call screen which will simply paste the number into the dialer
2. Take each digit in the number stored in the clipboard, and programatically press the keys on the phone pad which the user would otherwise touch
3. Open the incoming call in my own application which can answer the call and has the capability to paste/add numbers in the dialer
4. Override one of the keys on the numpad that pops up in a call (say the backspace key), and *reprogram* it to perform the function I want (so instead of backspacing, it would enter the saved number)

Are any of these at all possible (why or why not)? Or can you suggest any other way to accomplish what I want? Thanks, much obliged.

Edit: Let me be even more specific. This is the screen I am targeting:

[image]
[image: -]
I need *some* way to get a custom number into this field. It doesn't matter how, I just need a lead or a tip to get me on the right track. I have seen people make apps that are custom dialers, but all they do is take an entered number and call. If I have to make my own app, it has to be capable of picking up the call or accessing the picked up call, and populating the above field, or its own field that would serve the same function.

Comment: "I am working on an app that picks up a call, and in the dial pad during the active call, it enters a number previously saved or copied." - Can you describe the problem using more than just one sentence? What do you mean by "custom number"? Also, what do you mean by "app that picks up the call"?

Comment: @RajV Well, what I mean is that if it detects a certain incoming call number (the custom number the user can set), then my app would pick up the call instead of the default application, and I would be able to program the flexibility to enter a number into the dialpad within my own app. This is under the assumption that I can't add any numbers into the default app dialer (inside a call), and the additional assumption that I am allowed to write an app which picks up the call and handles it instead of the default android app. Does that make a little more sense? Thanks!

Comment: See my answer. To pick up an incoming call, you will need to use the internal ITelephony object. The same has a dial method that might allow you to punch in a few numbers in the dial pad. If this works out, there will be no need to write your own dialer.

Comment: @RajV Thanks, Raj! I'm very excited to try this out.

Comment: @capcom you succeded to dial out the number during call ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an API for that

The best way I'm thinking right now is to open an app during the call (maybe through Receiver) with a TextView where you can enter your text

Then here you can make your call :

```
Intent intentCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, null));
startActivity(intentCall);
```

But I don't know how the phone app will react

Comment: Thanks so much for answering. But as far as I understand, isn't the `intentCall` going to start a new call? Not make another call within the current one?

Comment: Yeah that's the missed part. I don't know how the current call will handle this new intent, will it stop the call and make a new one or will it put the call on hold and make the new one :s ?

Comment: I guess I'll try it, but I don't expect it work :( There *has* to be a way to do this!

Answer (score 2):

From the description you have given, it appears that you would require to use the telephony manager interface.
The problem you might face going forward with this idea for you would be that you would be trying to pick the call programatically and effectively change the phone state. In other words you would require the MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission. This permission has now been restricted to System apps only, starting from Gingerbread.
Without this basic permission, I think your application idea would not be very much fiesible. Further, since you would be trying to key in numbers programatically, which i am assuming is for the purpose of sending DTMF tones, you would have the problem that in Android In Call Data is not accessible to applications.
As of now the support for a proper telephony package in Android is missing.
I hope the above clarifies some of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want the app to punch in a few numbers in the dial pad after a call is received.

The following may be an option worth trying.

Obtain the internal `com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony` object using `Java reflection`. [Details here](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html). Then call the `dial()` method. This method just adds the numbers to the dial pad but doesn't actually initiate a phone call. This might work for you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking into this now.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the documentation for the object? For example, I can't find the dial() function in the API anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I tried it, and it didn't work. It puts the number into the dialer after the call is over, but not in the active dialer while the call is ongoing (as seen in the pictures in my original post). If you would like to look at my code to see if you can figure anything out, that would be awesome. Thanks again, I wish it worked :(