# Neither user 10056 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, phone-call, telephonymanager

I want to create such an application in which i want to open a dialer with specified number during call.

I have successfully opened the dialer during a call with refrence of this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109554/android-dialing-a-custom-number-once-call-picked-up) but not able to dial the number, and another issue is that code is not working above Android 2.2. is there any other way to make this working in all devices.

**Code :**

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);
ITelephony telephonyService;
telephonyService = (ITelephony)m.invoke(tm);

// Silence the ringer and answer the call!
telephonyService.silenceRinger();
telephonyService.answerRingingCall();
telephonyService.showCallScreen();
telephonyService.showCallScreenWithDialpad(true);
```

**ERROR LOG:**

```
01-09 17:35:41.065: W/Resources(367): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x2 a=-1}
01-09 17:38:23.446: W/System.err(367): java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10056 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.
01-09 17:38:23.446: W/System.err(367):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
01-09 17:38:23.446: W/System.err(367):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
01-09 17:38:23.446: W/System.err(367):  at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.silenceRinger(ITelephony.java:549)
01-09 17:38:23.446: W/System.err(367):  at com.everysoft.autoanswer.AutoAnswerIntentService.answerPhoneAidl(AutoAnswerIntentService.java:137)
01-09 17:38:23.446: W/System.err(367):  at com.everysoft.autoanswer.AutoAnswerIntentService.onHandleIntent(AutoAnswerIntentService.java:94)
01-09 17:38:23.446: W/System.err(367):  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
01-09 17:38:23.446: W/System.err(367):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-09 17:38:23.446: W/System.err(367):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-09 17:38:23.446: W/System.err(367):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

**EDIT**

I am able to auto answer the call in all devices but having problem with opening a dialpad only.

Comment: please would you like to tell me how can you answer programmatically to phone call, i want it to answer programmatically, but i don't know how to do ut

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line and your code should work:

```
telephonyService.silenceRinger();
```

That is an invalid call after Android 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried like bellow ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1231231234"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: it will place new call

Comment: then what is ur requirement?

Comment: want to send DTMF during call

Comment: As per my knowdedge u r not allowed to do that. What u r trying to do in above code is short of hacking not a standard way to do.

Comment: I want develop feature like callback, so what will be the exact process to do that? or its not possible in Android  ?

Answer (score 1):

MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission used by system apps only not by third party apps.

Instead of using answerRingingCall(), u can use key events Like:

```
Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, 
new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
```

Comment: I am able to answer the call in all devices but having problem with opening a dialpad only.

Comment: @user543: Not working, is there any other solution for accept call

Answer (score 0):

Add in manifest permission `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE`

Comment: Please check this [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_PHONE_STATE). `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` cannot be used by 3rd party apps.

Comment: MODIFY_PHONE_STATE is a private permission only available for System Apps

Answer (score 0):

I thing you use the hiden library **com.android.internal.telephony** I add this line in the manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

and I worked in my case I tried it in 4.4.2

Comment: cannot add it, says that this permission is only granted to system apps.